# How to count a list of rows words

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to do a word counting of the 100 first rows of my data frame df5.  I am trying to get this kind of result

[image]

```py
#filterin first 100 rows
df6 = df5.select("text_")
df6_100rows = df6.head(100)
#this save a list of rows
print(df6_100rows)
#[Row(text_='"@MJCH85 Just say ""Alexa'), Row(text_='@ChandleeStyle That is defi

#word count
#I convert my list to RDD
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext.getOrCreate()

#JAVA
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/drive/MyDrive/IDS561_BigData/spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop3.2"

#Counting the words in the data frame
counts = rdd100rows.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b).collect()
print(counts)
```

I get an error which I presume has something to do with the fact that I got a list of rows (the code works well with an RDD made from a regular list)... but I am not sure about this or how to fix it. Also, I am working in collab.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To could words from first 100 sentences stored in *text_* column in DataFrame:

```
(
    df.limit(100)
    .select(
        F.explode(
            F.split("text_", " ")
        ).alias("Word")
    )
    .groupBy("Word")
    .count()
    .withColumnRenamed("count", "Frequency")
    .show()
)
```